# How to sign ClickOnce application in Post Build Event?

Tags: c#, clickonce, signing, signtool

I have WinForms application that are deployed through ClickOnce.
I have Post Build Event that signs my assemblies with SignTool.
I publish application as ClickOnce installer and I see in VS output that files are signed, but after install there is no signed assemblies.
How I can sign assemblies that will be included to ClickOnce package?

Comment: Read  "#2: Signing the application executable post-build" --> https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/windows-8-and-clickonce-the-definitive-answer-2/

Comment: I do exactly this, but files are not signed

Comment: Verify "obj" directory  ( for VS2013 try  "$(ProjectDir)obj\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetFileName)" ) and check the log on VS output view.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally I did that!!! You are right, the problem was because I signed assembly in bin/Release folder, not in obj! Also I set AfterCompile target, because I had problems with application manifest with BeforePublish target.

Comment: Great! Mark your answer as correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [Mate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895279/mate)

Finally I did that! I added target to *.cproj file as mentioned in article [here](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/windows-8-and-clickonce-the-definitive-answer-2/)

It looks like:

```
<Target Name="AfterCompile">
<Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\SignTool.exe&quot; sign /f cert.pfx /p your_password /v &quot;$(ProjectDir)obj/$(ConfigurationName)/$(TargetFileName)&quot;" />
</Target>
```

There is signed ***.exe** file in the **obj** directory. Also I use **AfterCompile** target, because I had problems with application manifest when tryed **BeforePublish** target.

Answer (score 0):

This has been significantly easened in VS2022

Add a PFX to your Certificates store

[image: 1]

Then add the following line to Post-Build Events
[image: 2]